# Strange behaviour of new mysql json selection syntax with Laravel

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So, I am using HighCharts Heatmap chart.

Here is the demo which I took as boilerplate: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap/

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/g3Lu51va/1/

```php
Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'heatmap',
                marginTop: 40,
                marginBottom: 80,
                plotBorderWidth: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
            },

            yAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                categories: [
                    '00:00 - 01:00',
                    '01:00 - 02:00',
                    '02:00 - 03:00',
                    '03:00 - 04:00',
                    '04:00 - 05:00',
                    '05:00 - 06:00',
                    '06:00 - 07:00',
                    '07:00 - 08:00',
                    '08:00 - 09:00',
                    '09:00 - 10:00',
                    '10:00 - 11:00',
                    '11:00 - 12:00',
                    '12:00 - 1z:00',
                    '13:00 - 14:00',
                    '14:00 - 15:00',
                    '15:00 - 16:00',
                    '16:00 - 17:00',
                    '17:00 - 18:00',
                    '18:00 - 19:00',
                    '19:00 - 20:00',
                    '20:00 - 21:00',
                    '21:00 - 22:00',
                    '22:00 - 23:00',
                    '23:00 - 00:00',
                ],
                title: null
            },

            colorAxis: {
                min: 0,
                minColor: '#FFFFFF',
                maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            },

            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                layout: 'vertical',
                margin: 0,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 25,
                symbolHeight: 280
            },

            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> spent <br><b>' +
                        this.point.value + '</b> hours on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
                }
            },

            credits: false,

            series: [{
                name: 'Sales per employee',
                borderWidth: 1,

                borderColor: '#c05e7d', // not works
                color: '#4eb798', // not works

                data: [[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[2,0,0],[3,0,0],[4,0,0],[5,0,0],[6,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0],[2,1,0],[3,1,0],[4,1,0],[5,1,0],[6,1,0],[0,2,0],[1,2,0],[2,2,0],[3,2,0],[4,2,0],[5,2,0],[6,2,0],[0,3,0],[1,3,0],[2,3,0],[3,3,0],[4,3,0],[5,3,0],[6,3,0],[0,4,0],[1,4,0],[2,4,0],[3,4,0],[4,4,0],[5,4,0],[6,4,0],[0,5,0],[1,5,0],[2,5,0],[3,5,0],[4,5,0],[5,5,0],[6,5,0],[0,6,0],[1,6,0],[2,6,0],[3,6,0],[4,6,0],[5,6,0],[6,6,0],[0,7,0],[1,7,0],[2,7,0],[3,7,0],[4,7,0],[5,7,0],[6,7,0],[0,8,90],[1,8,0],[2,8,0],[3,8,0],[4,8,0],[5,8,0],[6,8,0],[0,9,60],[1,9,0],[2,9,0],[3,9,0],[4,9,0],[5,9,0],[6,9,0],[0,10,0],[1,10,0],[2,10,0],[3,10,0],[4,10,0],[5,10,0],[6,10,0],[0,11,0],[1,11,0],[2,11,0],[3,11,0],[4,11,0],[5,11,0],[6,11,0],[0,12,0],[1,12,0],[2,12,0],[3,12,0],[4,12,0],[5,12,0],[6,12,0],[0,13,0],[1,13,0],[2,13,0],[3,13,0],[4,13,0],[5,13,0],[6,13,0],[0,14,0],[1,14,0],[2,14,0],[3,14,0],[4,14,0],[5,14,0],[6,14,0],[0,15,0],[1,15,0],[2,15,0],[3,15,0],[4,15,0],[5,15,0],[6,15,0],[0,16,0],[1,16,0],[2,16,0],[3,16,0],[4,16,0],[5,16,0],[6,16,0],[0,17,0],[1,17,0],[2,17,0],[3,17,0],[4,17,0],[5,17,0],[6,17,0],[0,18,0],[1,18,0],[2,18,0],[3,18,0],[4,18,0],[5,18,0],[6,18,0],[0,19,0],[1,19,0],[2,19,0],[3,19,0],[4,19,0],[5,19,0],[6,19,0],[0,20,0],[1,20,0],[2,20,0],[3,20,0],[4,20,0],[5,20,0],[6,20,0],[0,21,0],[1,21,0],[2,21,0],[3,21,0],[4,21,0],[5,21,0],[6,21,0],[0,22,0],[1,22,0],[2,22,0],[3,22,0],[4,22,0],[5,22,0],[6,22,0],[0,23,0],[1,23,0],[2,23,0],[3,23,0],[4,23,0],[5,23,0],[6,23,0]],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000'
                }
            }]

        });
```

And here I marked elements shown weird with my comments and questions:

[image]

So, as you may see, my data (xAxis->categories && yAxis->categories && series->data) is in one format, but it shown absolutely weirdly. What am I missing? Google said nothing.
Also I tried to change plot size but there are no any effects. I think I am missing something fundamental.

1. why is there such a strange time format on Y axis is rendered (without some ranges which are included in my xAxis object configuration);
2. why not zeros are rendered as labels for the series (reference to the series data property);
3. why the [0,9,60] data is rendered, but [0,8,90] not (same strange behaviour as in second question);

so, these questions are represented on the screen above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `[0,8,90]` for the 8th(9) cell in the first(0) column and `[0,9,60]` for the 9th(10) cell of the first(0) column. What's the question?

Comment: 1. why is there such a strange time format on Y axis is rendered (without some ranges which are included in my xAxis object configuration);
2. why not zeros are rendered as labels for the series (reference to the series data property);
3. why the [0,9,60] data is rendered, but [0,8,90] not (same strange behaviour as in second question);

so, these questions are represented on the screen above.

Comment: I think that 90 is invisible due to plot size. But the cells are colored appropriately, so there is only the label that's invisible. Try to increase the height of the diagram. Is it better this way: https://jsfiddle.net/g3Lu51va/2/ ?